# "exec" is exiting the script and not proceeding to next step

Tags: linux, bash, exec

We are trying to capture return code of exec command but once the command is executed the script is getting exit without proceeding to next lines.

```
exec /bin/sh -c $command > log.txt
rc=$?
if [ $rc -ne 0 ]; then echo "script failed"; exit 999 ; fi
```

Any suggestion how to make the "exec" command execute and then make the next set of lines to continue

Answer (score 6):

[`exec`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#exec) with a command as argument replaces the current program running in the process with the named command, so from the perspective of the calling shell script it never returns, even if `exec` fails to actually run the requested command.

In your scenario you should probably drop `exec`:

```sh
/bin/sh -c " $command" > log.txt
rc=$?
if [ "$rc" -ne 0 ]; then echo>&2 "script failed"; exit 99; fi
```

Also note the quotes around `$command` which you forgot, and the leading space to avoid problems with `$command` code that start with `-`. And the `>&2` to make sure the error is sent to stderr.

The error code was changed from 999 to 99 as anything above 255 yields unspecified results.

If  the point is to have the shell code stored in `$command` interpreted by the current shell, then you'd use `eval`:

```sh
eval " $command" > log.txt
rc=$?
if [ "$rc" -ne 0 ]; then echo>&2 "script failed"; exit 99; fi
```

Or better:

```bash
if ! eval " $command" > log.txt; then
  echo>&2 "script failed"
  exit 99
fi
```

Note that in POSIX `sh`, `eval` being also a so-called *special* builtin is also required to exit when it fails like when there's a syntax error in the code or the `> log.txt` redirection fails. In those cases, the `script failed` error would not be output. That can be worked around with:

```bash
if ! command eval " $command" > log.txt; then
  echo>&2 "script failed"
  exit 99
fi
```

Where the `command` prefix removes its *specialness* to the following special builtin.

You can't use that in `zsh` if not in `sh` emulation.

Comment: @Stéphane I was about to change the description of `exec`’s exit behaviour ;-). Are there any (non-POSIX) shells where it *doesn’t* exit in all cases when a command is specified?

Comment: I wouldn't expect so. Note that there's a similar requirement for `eval` which is ignored by default in some shells when not in POSIX mode.

Comment: An interactive shell such as `bash` won't honour `exec` if the target is missing (eg `exec thisdoesnotexist`). Likewise setting `shopt -s execfail` (again, `bash`). Both cases return status 127 if exec fails